# WordPress-driven, single-page app with universal JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, wordpress, reactjs

Is it possible to deliver a WordPress-driven, single-page application using isomorphic/universal JavaScript techniques (with frameworks such as React and Angular2)?

Comment: To me this sounds like a bit of an experiment. It's rather unclear what the benefit of using React here is. You mentioned performance, but it's not that much faster, if at all, depending on what your bottlenecks are.

Comment: One of the major features that users interact with a lot is filtering/searching/sorting. And I'd like to make different pages on the site behave more like a web app. From my understanding, the virtual DOM — and the way that it re-renders only what is necessary — will make this a lot faster. Am I wrong here?

Comment: The speed improvements are mostly negligible--certainly not worth re-architecting an entire application for. For instance, Angular applications can be known to get choppy when re-rendering many elements at once, however easily optimized with a few lines of code (no VDOM required). That said, React is a fantastic piece of technology, but performance shouldn't be your reason to switch.

Comment: If you're unable to get a good answer here, it might be worth posting instead on Wordpress Stack Exchange - some more WP experts there. FWIW I think it's a decent question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After building a few single-page applications with React, I'll try to answer this for anyone else who might land here in the future.

**Universal/Isomorphic JavaScript**

If you're not already familiar with this buzzword (made mainstream by articles on [Airbnb](http://nerds.airbnb.com/isomorphic-javascript-future-web-apps/) and [Medium](https://medium.com/@mjackson/universal-javascript-4761051b7ae9)), it essentially refers to the ability to render JavaScript on both the server side and client side.

**Pitfalls of JavaScript MVC Frameworks**

Single-page applications have become tremendously popular, primarily for their ability to provide a more fluid user experience — similar to desktop and mobile apps (e.g. no page reloads).

However, first-generation frameworks (such as Angular and Backbone) had one major drawback: their dependency on client-side rendering. This [presented a few problems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wvZ7gakqV4):

- Doesn't work at all if the user has JavaScript disabled.
- Can't be crawled by search engines (although [Google is now making significant progress](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157) in how it handles JavaScript).
- Users are initially served a blank page while they wait upwards of eight seconds (or more) for the content to render.
- Social sharing is handicapped (no previews available).

**Today's Solution**

Newer frameworks/libraries (including Angular2 and React) are capable of supporting server-side rendering in addition to client-side rendering (when used with Node.js on the backend).

The idea is that you serve up content initially through the server, and then hand off routing to the client. This technique gives you the best of both worlds — a search-engine friendly app that loads instantly and doesn't require page reloads.

**Evolution of WordPress**

[WordPress is now moving towards becoming a fully-fledged application framework](http://v2.wp-api.org/) and is in the process of adding the WP REST API to WordPress Core. This (in combination with the technologies mentioned above) gives us the ability to create truly universal applications while using WordPress to serve our data. And in fact, that's exactly what [WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.com/calypso/) and [others](https://hmn.md/wordpress-case-study/ustwo/) are already doing.